# How to get a list on Windows Phone 8.1 using WebApi

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How can I do a GET using Windows Phone based on my Web API code? To make a Post i already know and Works for me, but i don't know to retrieve a list of Collections from my API, Thanks!

My API Code:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private ApiDatabaseEntities data = new ApiDatabaseEntities();

    public IHttpActionResult GetUsuarios()
    {           
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Usuario> usuarios = data.Usuario.AsEnumerable();
            return Ok(usuarios.AsEnumerable());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        } 
    }
    public IHttpActionResult PostUsuarios(Usuario usuario)
    {
        try
        {
            data.Usuario.Add(usuario);
            data.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And here is my Windows phone code:

1 - WebApiBase

```
public abstract class WebApiBase<T>
{
    private string Url = "http://localhost:63964/api/users";

    protected virtual void Post(object objectPost)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.PostAsJsonAsync(Url, objectPost);
    }     
    public abstract void Send(T objectPost);

}
```

2 - And UsuarioApi

```
public class UsuarioApi : WebApiBase<Models.UserPhone>
{
    public override void Send(UserPhone objectPost)
    {
        this.Post(objectPost);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Sending get request to server from Windows Phone and then handling the response from server.

```
public async void GetRequest(){                string url = "APIurl";
                HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage _response = await _client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
                if (_response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string APIResponse = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(APIResponse).ToObject<MyClass>();
                }
}
```

and MyClass

```
public class MyClass
{
public ObservableCollection<CollectionClass> _myCollection{get;set;}
}

public class CollectionClass
{
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and now You can perform operations on myObject as per your requirement.